# Firefox plugin that modify page DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, service, firefox-addon

I'm working on a Firefox sidebar plugin, using Jetpack, able to interact with the browser contents, in particular my goal is to be able from the plugin to select the web page DOM objects and collect informations from the page inside my plugin.

My main point is that I would like to access to the web page from a script that is not directly inside the plugin itself:

the plugin may load an external service (from my server) and may access to the web browser page DOM.

This due the fact I would like to separate the sidebar-firefox plugin from the real business logic, in order to change that without releasing another plugin...

Is it possible? And, if yes, how?

Comment: I think it is possible, but the plugin that you are creating will have problems if you try to validate and update the extension to Addons Marketplace. If this is not an issue you can attach a script to the page and load the JS from your server. Then you can access the DOM.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The purpose of the plugin is not to be delivered on the Add-on Marketplace, so I guess it is not an issue.
Do you have any idea how to include the scripts?

Comment: Are you using jpm or something else to build from addon?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Jetpack / JPM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach a worker to any new tab such as:
`main.js`:

```
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");

pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "*",
  contentScriptWhen: 'ready',
  contentScriptFile: [
    data.url("jquery.min.js"),
    data.url("script.js")
  ]
});
```

The above code just attaches jquery and you script.js to any page. You can find more options about attaching scripts [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod). Note: the script.js and the jquery.min.js should be in the `./data/` folder of the extension.

Now, we have the `script.js` running on every page. How we can execute code from another server?

You can use the [jQuery.getScript()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/) to achieve that.

For example in your `script.js`:

```
var url = "https://code.jquery.com/color/jquery.color.js";
$.getScript( url, function() {
  $( "#go" ).click(function() {
    $( ".block" )
      .animate({
        backgroundColor: "rgb(255, 180, 180)"
      }, 1000 )
      .delay( 500 )
      .animate({
        backgroundColor: "olive"
      }, 1000 )
      .delay( 500 )
      .animate({
        backgroundColor: "#00f"
      }, 1000 );
  });
});
```

You can modify the script.js to your own needs.

Answer (score 0):

Quite old feature now, [Browser Extensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions) would be probably better (4 FF >=57)...
Tampermonkey looks like a nice and complete solution - very easy to create, publish or debug such scripts.